# I am getting msg.trim is not a function when trying to start new app with ionic

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

Here is error:

TypeError: msg.trim is not a function
    at Logger.log (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/utils/logger.js:78:21)
    at Logger.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/utils/logger.js:35:14)
    at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/dist/index.js:186:22)
    at Generator.throw ()
    at rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:101:69)
    at

and here is the command which I am running:

**$ ionic start myApp**

my node.js version is **v8.9.1** and npm is **5.5.1**

This what I found in logger.js file

```
log(level, msg) {
    if (this.shouldLog(level)) {
        let prefix = this.prefix;
        if (typeof msg === 'function') {
            msg = msg();
        }
        if (prefix) {
            if (typeof prefix === 'function') {
                prefix = prefix();
            }
            msg = util.format(prefix, msg);
        }
        const color = this.getStatusColor(level);
        const status = color.bold.bgBlack;
        const b = chalk_1.default.dim;
        const msgLines = format_1.wordWrap(msg, { indentation: level === 'info' ? 0 : level.length + 3 }).split('\n');
        if (msg.trim().includes('\n')) {
            msg = msgLines.map((l, i) => {
                // We want these log messages to stand out a bit, so automatically
                // color the first line and separate the first line from the other
                // lines if the message is multi-lined.
                if (i === 0 && this.firstLineColored.includes(level)) {
                    return color(l) + (msgLines.length > 1 ? '\n' : '');
                }
                return l;
            }).join('\n') + '\n\n';
        }
        else {
            msg = msgLines.join('\n');
        }
        msg = this.enforceLF(msg);
        const fmtLevel = () => b('[') + status(level.toUpperCase()) + b(']');
        if (level !== 'info') {
            msg = `${fmtLevel()} ${msg}`;
        }
        this.stream.write(util.format(msg));
    }
```

Comment: What have you done to try and fix it?

Comment: I tried to install and reinstall the node, ionic and updating brew moreover, I tried all this to one of my friend and everything was fine.

Comment: Can you post some code? Maybe where you are using said msg.trim? You could have forgotten to require it in the node, or something. I don't really know much of ionic, but it will help you get more people to answer.

Comment: Hey @Ted I tried to find out on this location /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/utils/logger.js as you can see in error log. 

And I am going to update my question with code that is written in that file.

Comment: The issue is that logger isn't something you can change because it's part of the package `ionic` that you installed. The error is most likely not there (as millions use it and it would have been fixed already). Could you remove that and instead post the code where you import the ionic app? Like your server.js file or index, or wtv.

Comment: Also, is there any more error in the error message, or just that?

Comment: Just that, and I just following ionic framework website's intructions to create an app. After install everything I tried to run $ ionic start myApp command.

Comment: Yeah I don't really know. I hope someone helps you then, good luck!